# HTC Desire won't boot - buzzes 7 times instead

Tags: htc-desire, boot

I've just bought an HTC Desire and it seems to have stopped working.

On startup, I just get the O2 splash page, then it buzzes 7 times, and that's it.

I tried holding down the Vol down key, then the power button, and it gets me into some menu called HBOOT.  There is a recovery option in there, but it just reboots the phone, and I'm back where I started.

How do I wipe the thing and get it starting up again?

Comment: I don't know if this is necessarily the same for the Desire, but in my experience with other HTC phones this is often indicative of a hardware fault that is not going to be fixable. The vibrating is basically a Qualcomm (the system-on-a-chip the phone uses) error code.

Comment: The reason I think that this is software problem is because it was plugged into my computer via USB while I tried to remote debug it using eclipse.

Comment: You should put your Update as answer to your own question and mark it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up and returned the phone to the guy I bought it from on eBay, saying it was faulty. My conclusion was that it was an intermittent hardware fault.

Answer (score 0):

when u go into recovery try to wipe cache...